# SageMaker deploy error "serve" executable file not found in $PATH

Tags: docker, deployment, amazon-sagemaker

In Amazon SageMaker, I'm trying to deploy a custom created Docker container with a Scikit-Learn model, but deploying keeps giving errors.

These are my steps:

- On my local machine created a script (script.py) and splitted training and test data. The script contains a main section, accepts parameters 'output-train-dir', 'model-dir', 'train' and 'test', and contains the functions model_fn, input_fn, output_fn and predict_fn
- Tested the script locally, which worked

  - python script.py --train . --test . --model-dir .
- Created a Docker image based on the default Python image (Python 3.9) and push to Amazon ECR, below are the commands I've used

  ```
   > docker pull python
   create Dockerfile, containing
      FROM python:3.9
      RUN pip3 install --no-cache scikit-learn numpy pandas joblib sagemaker-training
   > docker build -t mymodel .
   > aws ecr create-repository --repository-name mymodel
   > docker tag 123456789012 123456789123.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/mymodel
   > docker push 123456789123.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/mymodel
  ```
- Uploaded the training and test data to s3 (mybucket)
- Trained the script with local modus

  ```
   aws_sklearn = SKLearn(entry_point='script.py',
                         framework_version='0.23-1',
                         image_uri='123456789123.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/mymodel',
                         instance_type='local',
                         role=role)
   aws_sklearn.fit({'train': mybucket_train_path, 'test': mybucket_test_path, 'model-dir': mybucket_model_path})
  ```

which was successful

- Next I trained on AWS

  ```
    aws_sklearn = SKLearn(entry_point='script.py',
                          framework_version='0.23-1',
                          image_uri='123456789123.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/mymodel',
                          instance_type='ml.m4.xlarge',
                          role=role)
    aws_sklearn.fit({'train': mybucket_train_path, 'test': mybucket_test_path})
  ```

which also was successful (however, providing the model-dir paramater gave errors, so I omitted it)

- deploying however gave an error:

  ```
    aws_sklearn_predictor = aws_sklearn.deploy(instance_type='ml.t2.medium',
                                               initial_instance_count=1)
  ```

Error message:

> UnexpectedStatusException: Error hosting endpoint
> mymodel-2021-01-24-12-52-02-790: Failed. Reason:  The primary
> container for production variant AllTraffic did not pass the ping
> health check. Please check CloudWatch logs for this endpoint..

And Cloudwatch said:

> AWS sagemaker exec: "serve": executable file not found in $PATH

I somewhere read that I should add RUN chmod +x /opt/program/serve to the Dockerfile, but in my local image, there is no serve file present, this is something that SageMaker creates, right ?

How or where should I add serve to the $PATH environment variable or grant execute rights to the serve script ?

Answer (score 3):

The **serve** file isn't something SageMaker creates automatically; you have to have it be part of the Docker container. This is technically true for the Estimator job too (there should be a similar *train* file as well; however you overwrite this by manually specifying an `entry_point`).

[This page](https://sagemaker-workshop.com/custom/containers.html) should help explain what SageMaker is actually trying to run when you run training and batch_transform jobs. That page references [this repo](https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/master/advanced_functionality/scikit_bring_your_own/scikit_bring_your_own.ipynb) which you can use as an example.

In short, if you want to continue to use your custom docker container, you'll have to build in functionality for the *serve* command (See additional scripts in the repo for launching the gunicorn server which runs multiple instances of the Flask app) and add those files to your Dockerfile.

The `RUN chmod +x /opt/program/serve` command will also make more sense after you've added that `serve` command functionality.

Comment: Thanks I'm going to try that and will get back to you. Didn't know that page, seems like a comprehensive explanation !

Comment: This saved my day, thanks a lot!!